# Extracting SQL values into powershell variables?

Tags: sql, powershell, variables, sharepoint-2013

I currently have the following script:

```
$SQLServer = "sqldev1" 
$SQLDBName = "SPDEV_Printing" 
$SqlQuery = "select * from PcBeheerPrinter WHERE PRT_name = 'bwpsc006'" 

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True" 

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery 
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection 

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd 

$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet 
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) 

$SqlConnection.Close() 

clear 

$DataSet.Tables[0]
```

which returns some console output like this:

```
    PRT_PrintServerName     : pcounter
PRT_Name                : bwpsc006
PRT_PortNameFull        : PCOUNT_bwpsc006
PRT_CAL_SerialNumber    :
PRT_ACTIVE              : 1
PRT_CAL_RespondToPing   : 1
PRT_CAL_NamePinged      : bwpsc006
PRT_CAL_FirstSeendate   : 8/02/2017 20:55:13
PRT_CAL_LastSeendate    : 4/12/2017 11:36:19
PRT_CAL_SNMPPossible    : 1
PRT_CAL_Brand           :
PRT_ShareName           : bwpsc006
PRT_Comment             :
PRT_Datatype            : RAW
PRT_DriverName          : Canon iR-ADV C5045/5051 PCL6
PRT_Location            :
PRT_PrintProcessor      :
PRT_Published           : 0
PRT_Shared              : 0
PRT_NumberOfMissedPings : 0
PRT_LastResponsedate    : 4/12/2017 11:36:19
PRT_RenderingMode       : CSR
```

My question is: How do I transfer some of these values into PS variables? 
I need the Name, SerialNumber and some others (these will do as example) to eventually transfer them to a SharePoint list. 
I'm still a beginner and can't figure it out through googling.

Thanks!

Comment: `$Name = $DataSet.Tables[0].PRT_Name`; `$SerialNo = $DataSet.Tables[0].PRT_CAL_SerialNumber` and so on!

Comment: Thank you! Feel free to reply this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand` class, most of the objects returned will be of type `datatable`. Since, `$DataSet` will be of type datatable, you can directly use all the returned properties like this -

`$Name = $DataSet.Tables[0].PRT_Name; 
$SerialNo = $DataSet.Tables[0].PRT_CAL_SerialNumber`  and so on.

You can then use the variables `$Name` and `$Serialno` as input to your SharePoint List.

Answer (score 1):

If the data type is object, then you can directly use the *select-object* like:

```
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Select-object  PRT_Name,PRT_CAL_SerialNumber
```